# remove text when click left-click on entry tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been recently trying to make entry text disappear in python tkinter to show the user where to enter something specific but what happens when I enter text that it will be there and the user have to delete all of the text by hand
This is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root )
entry.insert(0, "enter the text here")
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can bind a callback function with left-click mouse event on the entry widget, the callback function will delete the text from the widget when the event is triggered. Add `entry.bind("<1>", lambda _: entry.delete(0, 'end'))`. See [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/bind.htm) to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the left click with `entry.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: entry.delete(0, tk.END))`.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: entry.delete(0, tk.END))
entry.insert(0, "enter the text here")
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```